# Difference between ANSI art and Linux Terminal ANSI escapes codes

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, ansi

I just found one ANSI escape that is different in ANSI art and in Linux Terminal.

```
[0;5;47;30m
```

The problem is this ANSI Art https://16colo.rs/pack/blocktronics-b-sides/om%20-%20bjork%20-%20debut.ans

this is rendered as while in PabloDraw but it's blinking in Linux Terminal (part of the face), because `5` according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) is "Rapid Blink" but it's also in MS-Dos it seems. But 47;30 is black background and gray color (color is named as white but it's gray in Wikipedia and Linux Terminal).

Anybody know why it should render as white? Is this some kind of exception? Is this documented somewhere? Are there any other things like this that should work differently than on Linux Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of [CGA’s implementation of blinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter#Textmode_color). On CGA, the fourth bit of the background colour controls either blinking or high intensity, depending on the setting of another hardware register. Thus with `ANSI.SYS` on MS-DOS, `ESC[1m` and `ESC[5m` could end up being interchangeable...

In my quick tests on DOS, `ESC[1m` doesn’t actually change anything, and `ESC[5m` is required to get high intensity background colours.

Comment: [Also OS/2, and note `linux-16color`.](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5682#issuecomment-624583284)