# Problematic [0;5;30m ANSI Code in ANSI Art

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, ansi

I have another question about ANSI Art. The problem is this file https://16colo.rs/pack/lgcy-003/hayn9-smaller.ans

It have "à" character (the women in ANSI Art have it inside medalion on her neck).

[image: part of ANSI Art]

And just before that, there is this sequence of ANSI Escape codes:

```
[0;5;30mà
```

In [Difference between ANSI art and Linux Terminal ANSI escapes codes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/611821/1806) I was told that `5m` works the same as bold `1m`, but something else need to happen here because it some how get gray background and black color. Even that 30 is Foreground Black which for bold it should make it gray color on black background.

Can someone explain what this sequence should do in ANSI Art?

The only way to make this work is if 5 is reversed colors and bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in [blocktronics/moebius ANSI Art editor source code](https://github.com/blocktronics/moebius/) on GitHub.

The blink flag change bold only for the background. And normal bold change bold for color.

This can be found in this file [app/libtextmode/ansi.js@0ff8f66#L203](https://github.com/blocktronics/moebius/blob/0ff8f6623f939aaae6c02d31eb0674837c833001/app/libtextmode/ansi.js#L203).